# How to show an error message next to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing a validation on a directive, forcing the user to check the box. If the checkbox is not marked, an error message appears. My problem is that the message shifts to the text of the checkbox.

[image]

I need the validation message at the end. I need to do this in the directive, I do not want to touch controller or template.
How can do it?

```
    app.directive('validate', function ($timeout) {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel', 

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              if (!ngModel){
                return;          
              }
              ngModel.$setValidity('validation', false);

              scope.directive_function= function(){
                alert("directive function");
              }

              ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){
                if(val==true){
                  ngModel.$setValidity('validation', true);
                  var elemento_eliminar=(angular.element((document.getElementById('errorchec' ))));
                  elemento_eliminar.remove();
                }else{
                 ngModel.$setValidity('validation', false);
                 var newDirective = angular.element('<div id="errorchec" class="span_wrong" style="margin-top:5px; color:red">'+"must be required"+'</div>');
                element.after(newDirective);
                }
              })
           }


        };
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/venzoub4/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the `position:absolute` css property to align the validation

```
<div id="errorchec" class="span_wrong" 
style="position: absolute;margin-top:5px;color:red;">must be required</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/venzoub4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

To make it appear next to the input element add `display: inline-block` to the `div` element or simply use `span`.

```
<div id="errorchec" class="span_wrong" 
     style="margin-top:5px; color:red; display: inline-block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="check1"  value='value1' validate />value1</label>
```

your HTML has a `<label>` with an `<input>` and some text `value1` inside it.  The `input` is the element which is referred to by the directive;  the directive correctly put the error `<div>` after the `input`, but before the text.

Instead, you actually want the error outside the `<label>`.  To do this, reference the `.parent` of the element.

```
element.parent().after(newDirective);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b1qnny6a/